# Use xifthen package to determine if optional argument is provided

Tags: xifthen

I am trying to create a command `test` that takes 3 arguments.  The first argument is optional, while the second and third arguments are mandatory.

I am trying to use the [`xifthen`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen?lang=en) package, and specifically the `\xifthen` and `\isempty` commands therein, to test whether the optional argument is given.

- If the optional argument is NOT given, `test` should return "A".
- If the optional argument is given, `test` should return "B".

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[3]{%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{A}{B}
}

\begin{document}

\test{u}{v}
\\
\test[something]{u}{v}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following output.  What is/are my mistake(s)?

[image: output]

Comment: your command has no optional argument but three mandatory arguments. Use `\newcommand{\test}[3][]{...`

Comment: you have defined a command with three mandatory arguments, you need  to supply the default value in \newcommand to make the first argument optional

Comment: don't you want to use `#1`  somewhere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I do; I was just debugging.  As you can see, I am a total novice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ahhh, thank you. I'm rather embarrassed, but thank you for being kind.

Comment: You showed a good, small, complete example, which made it easy to see your error. I see no need to be embarrassed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining a macro with three mandatory (that is, braced) arguments. You need a slightly different syntax in order to make the first argument optional.

On the other hand, you can use `\NewDocumentCommand`, provided by the `xparse` package that is currently part of the kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse}% not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{omm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{A}{B}%
}

\begin{document}

\test{u}{v}

\test[something]{u}{v}

\end{document}
```

This will print “A” and “B”.

The idea is basically the same as

```
\newcommand{\test}[3][SoMeTHiNGweIrd]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{SoMeTHiNGweIrd}}{A}{B}%
}
```

but the implementation is better; for instance, the `\IfNoValueTF` test is expandable, which `\ifthenelse` isn't. Care is taken that the string, here represented by `SoMeTHiNGweIrd` is really something that needs extra effort to be produced.

In `omm` we state the argument types:

- `o` is an optional argument with no default value; its absence makes the `\IfNoValueTF` test to return true;
- `m` is a mandatory argument.

---

Why are you getting that output? As I said, your macro takes three *mandatory* arguments. In the first call the arguments found are

1. `u`
2. `v`
3. `\\`

Since `u` is not empty, you get `B`.

In the second call the arguments are

1. `[`
2. `s`
3. `o`

Thus you get `B`, a space (because of the endline at the end of the `\ifthenelse` line, and then `mething]uv`

There are two spaces between the `B`'s: one is generated by the endline in the definition (as explained before) and one is the endline after `\\`. This token is not executed, because it has been absorbed as an unused argument, so the endline counts as a space.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You need to use the second optional argument of `\newcommand` so that `#1` is optional.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[3][--zzz--]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{--zzz--}}{A}{B with #1} [#2][#3]%
}

\begin{document}

\test{u}{v}

\test[something]{u}{v}

\end{document}
```